# ActiveMQ Artemis - how to delete and purge queues

Tags: console, activemq-artemis

I would like to clear and/or delete some queues from the ActiveMQ Artemis console. I googled a bit and see some suggestions including scripts and commands, but actually haven't found anything showing how it can be done from the console. Is there a way to do this? If not, what is the simplest way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete and/or purge a queue from the ActiveMQ Artemis web admin console. Just select the queue and use the "Delete Queue" tab, e.g.:
[image]

You can also perform these operations from the CLI commands provided by ActiveMQ Artemis in the `bin` directory, e.g.:

```
$ ./artemis queue purge --name myQueue
```

```
$ ./artemis queue delete --name myQueue
```